# how to do conditional replacing using vim

Tags: vim, replace, conditional-statements

I want to replace `word` with `WORD`,  but only on the lines which start with `-`. Anybody knows how to do it?

Comment: `:%s/^-\(.*\)word\(.*\)/\1WORD\2/g`

Comment: @srikanthradix well if you're doing that, why not `:%s/^-.*\zsword/WORD/g`

Comment: whoops, I screwed up.  If you want the `/g` to do anything, `\zs` won't help you.  You're better off using `\@<=`: `%s/\%(^-.*\)\@<=word/WORD/g`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
:%g/^-/s/word/WORD/g
```

it's just a normal search and replace, but using g// to filter the lines you want to run it on.

Comment: Note that the `%` is not necessary when you run `:g`. Also for the question asker it is worth mentioning `:v` that is similar to `:g` but filters the line *not* matching the pattern